Using L'Hopital to Show a Limit is 0.
I am working on a homework assignment and have the following question:

Use L'Hopital's rule to show that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^n}=0$

Now, I used L'Hopital's rule once and got $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\frac{2e^{-1/x^2}}{x^3}}{nx^{n-1}}$ and that can be simplified to $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{2e^{-1/x^2}}{nx^{n+2}}$
I realized that if I keep taking L'Hopital, won't the denominator just stick with a power of x and result in an indeterminate form of something over 0?
Am I missing something here? Thank you.

You are correct. Try a substitution $u = 1/x$ and work with $\lim_{u\to\infty} u^{2+n} e^{-u^2}$

First make the substitution $u=\frac{1}{x}$.

That helps, thank you!
